# Blender (Not Respond) issue on Macbook pro m1 pro chip

Tags: modeling, rendering, 3d-view

[image]Can anyone help me set up the ideal blender configurations on my MacBook? I want to ensure a smooth experience with the application, without encountering any issues. My MacBook is equipped with the M1 Pro Chip.

Thank you

---

and here's the used storge and I don't know why it's like that [image]

---

[image]It was an event set up with a stage, table with chairs and a ballroom floor size that what I was trying to render

Comment: what exactly are you trying to render if your scene has 87GB of memory? By that I mean that your scene is huge or really badly done, I render some huge scenes as well but I never went above 40GB

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.